# How to deploy with some different directories on different servers using capistrano?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I need to deploy on different servers using capistrano with few different directories on each server.I have a main trunk branch,  having 5 directories say web, log, legacy , common and config. Directory web have 40 directories say uploads,resources, project1 and project2, project3 etc.
Now I need to deploy server1 with whole code except project2,project3 and server2 with whole code except project1,project3 and server3 with all main directories and only 1 directory project3 from web directory.

I tried using copy_exclude parameter, it works but it can be tedious as well as error prone as it need to be monitored manually if anyone include any new directory in web as well as we miss to exclude any directory(being huge in number) for server3. 
Please let me know if there is a clean and easy way to do so.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I would really like to know same.